# CSS 3D animation?

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to create an animation where an image will be wrapped around a cylinder or a bottle.

I am using CSS3 and it works to certain extent. But I cannot find a way to bring the bottom half of the cylinder! the top part of it is what I need and the bottom half needs to be same as the top bit.

I've made a jsFiddle BUT the page is nothing like it on the jsFiddle as it is not showing the 3D. Please get the code from here and try it on a blank HTML page locally so you know what I am talking about:http://jsfiddle.net/crf121359/Kk7AB/

I just need to make the bottom half (the bottom circle) to be exactly same as the top half.

I did play around with the X/Y values and nothing seems to work!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description"    content="wrap an image around a 3D revolving cylinder using only HTML and CSS3 3D, tutorial" />
<meta name="keywords"       content="panorama how to wrap image around cylinder CSS3 3D tutorial wrapping a picture around a cylinder  " />
<meta name="copyright"      content="(c) 2011 - 2012" /> 
<meta name="author"     content="Preston E Hall, director@baloziproductions.com" />

<title>Image Wrapped Around Spinning Cylinder Using Pure CSS3 3D</title>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">

body    {background:#000;
    color:rgb(236,132,57)}

h1  {font:small-caps 167% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}

#container {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:450px;
    width:550px;
    -moz-perspective: 900px;      
    -webkit-perspective: 900}

#container:hover * {
    -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused}

#frame {width: 33px;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;  /* translate must be last */
    -moz-transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(125px,70px,50px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(125px,70px,50px);}

.strip {-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-animation: spin 15s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin 15s infinite linear}

.strip div {
    position: absolute;
    background:  url(http://thumbp2-ir2.thumb.mail.yahoo.com/tn?sid=24769798665600007&mid=AKoo5C4AABDQUg0%2FRwAAAHNDk2E&midoffset=2_0_0_1_7182251&partid=1.2&f=1726&fid=Inbox&w=614&h=503);  /* background image is 792px 320px, try with green-hills or thailand-sunrise.jpg */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: solid rgb(145,87,0);
    border-width: thin 10px;
    height:320px;
    width:33px;
    opacity: 100;
}

.strip .a {background-position: 0 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .b {background-position: 759px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .c {background-position: 726px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .d {background-position: 693px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px)}    

.strip .e {background-position: 660px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px)}    

.strip .f {background-position: 627px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .g {background-position: 594px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .h {background-position: 561px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px)}   

.strip .i {background-position: 528px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px)}   

.strip .j {background-position: 495px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .k {background-position: 462px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .l {background-position: 429px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px)}   

.strip .m {background-position: 396px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px)}       

.strip .n {background-position: 363px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .o {background-position: 330px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .p {background-position: 297px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px)}   

.strip .q {background-position: 264px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px)}   

.strip .r {background-position: 231px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .s {background-position: 198px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .t {background-position: 165px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px)}   

.strip .u {background-position: 132px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px)}   

.strip .v {background-position: 99px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .w {background-position: 66px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px)}

.strip .x {background-position: 33px 0;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px)}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0)}
    to   { -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg)}}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0)}
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg)}}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<h1>Image Wrapped Around A Spinning strip</h1>

<div id="frame">
<div class="strip">

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="e"></div>
<div class="f"></div>
<div class="g"></div>
<div class="h"></div>
<div class="i"></div>
<div class="j"></div>
<div class="k"></div>
<div class="l"></div>
<div class="m"></div>
<div class="n"></div>
<div class="o"></div>
<div class="p"></div>
<div class="q"></div>
<div class="r"></div>
<div class="s"></div>
<div class="t"></div>
<div class="u"></div>
<div class="v"></div>
<div class="w"></div>
<div class="d"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to mostly work if you have a good link to a background image and remove the border: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Kk7AB/1/

Comment: @j08691, as i said the code doesn't work on jsfiddle properly. use the code locally so you know what it looks like or it should look like! what is shown on jsfiddle noting like how it should be! and nothing to do with the image quality or the link to the image!

Comment: I am using Chrome, I had to throw `repeat-x` in there on `.strip div` 's `background-repeat`.  just to get the image to show in all the panels.  not sure what you are seeing?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't have anything to do with it. It simply displays the code you enter like any website. If it doesn't work on jsFiddle then you're not entering your code properly.

Comment: okay, jsfiddle or how it shows my code has nothing to do with my question!!!! I only posted the jsfiddle in case someone wants to get the code from there! Please read my question again!

Comment: you mean you want the same radius of circle on the bottom of the cylinder as on the top of the cylinder?

Comment: @Malachi, yes that is correct.

Comment: you should Accept either your answer or my answer. that way others looking for help know that this answer was resolved

Comment: @Malachi, I cannot accept my own answer for 2 days according to stackoverflow terms.

Comment: that's right, I forgot. my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing this line of code:

```
#container {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:450px;
    width:550px;
    -moz-perspective: 2000px;     
    -webkit-perspective: 2000}
```

Comment: @Malachi, I have no clue why it worked but when i changed the perspective values it did work. so i answered my own question. hope this code comes handy to someone else.

Comment: is that the perspective of the viewport, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

ok I did a little bit of playing with the CSS in that fiddle that @j08691 gave.  and I came up with this.

http://jsfiddle.net/QGEgv/

the only thing that I really changed was the `rotateX(10deg)` in both `-moz-transform` and `-webkit-transform-`  to `0deg`

```
#frame {width: 33px;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;  /* translate must be last */
-moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(125px,70px,50px);
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(125px,70px,50px);}
```

what happens is that to make it seem more "3D" when you tilted it by 10 degrees they brought the bottom out towards the user making it seem like it was closer to them. which in turn made the bottom bigger on the screen.